# Spark getting keys from key-value RDD

Tags: apache-spark

If I have an RDD that has key-value pair and I want to get only the key part, what is the most efficient way of doing it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is very simple `yourRDD.keys()`

Similarly you can get RDD with values by `youRDD.values()`

For this and other RDD transformations and actions see examples [here](http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/zhe/ZhenHeSparkRDDAPIExamples.html)